# Xamarin Xam.Plugins.Forms.Svg change SvgPath to rerender the image

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin, xamarin.forms, model-binding

I use Xam.Plugins.Forms.Svg to support svg images. I need to change the image, so I tried:

**binding in xaml**:

```
<abstractions:SvgImage
    SvgPath="{Binding CurrentWeather.IconSource, StringFormat='Umbrella.Images.{0:F0}.svg'}"
    ....
    />
```

**to change it directly from C#:**

```
icon.SvgPath = "Umbrella.Images." + currentWeather.IconSource + ".svg";
```

The SvgPath attribute does change, but the image doesn't rerender.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: does the source (icon) implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Jason My view-model does implement INotifyPropertyChanged and all labels do update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an *issue* in the way the renderers are written, you would need to create a **new** `SvgImage` object and replace the current on in your page the way the renderers work in order for the static `Image` to be updated from a new SVG file.

You can patch the renderers by overriding the `OnElementPropertyChanged` event and respond to `SvgPath` PropertyName changes:

iOS Example:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (e.PropertyName == "SvgPath")
    {
        var svgStream = _formsControl.SvgAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(_formsControl.SvgPath);
        var reader = new SvgReader(new StreamReader(svgStream), new StylesParser(new ValuesParser()), new ValuesParser());
        var graphics = reader.Graphic;
        var canvas = new ApplePlatform().CreateImageCanvas(graphics.Size);
        graphics.Draw(canvas);
        var image = canvas.GetImage();
        var uiImage = image.GetUIImage();
        Control.Image = uiImage;
    }
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/blob/eab230fcf4158a288387727c15903a954e01cdaa/SVG/SVG/SVG.Forms.Plugin.Android/SvgImageRenderer.cs

Ref: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/blob/eab230fcf4158a288387727c15903a954e01cdaa/SVG/SVG/SVG.Forms.Plugin.iOS/SvgImageRenderer.cs

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need.